Does God specifically reveal Himself to individuals he would like to save?
From a personal Christian experience, it is as if God chooses those he will save by revealing Himself to those he deems worthy, this can be backed up by these examples from the Bible.

God reveals Himself to Abraham by having a direct conversation with him and ordering him to go to an unknown land.
God reveals Himself to Paul on his way to Damascus and engages him in a conversation like the previous case
Jesus calls the twelve and reveals his divine power to them through the miracles he performed
God reveals Himself to Moses via a burning bush
God reveals Himself to Samuel by calling him in his sleep
God reveals Himself to Elisha through the signs and wonders of Elijah
God reveals Himself to the parents of Samson and foretell his destiny
God reveals Himself to Jeremiah by telling him He knew him before he was formed in his mother's womb

From all these Biblical stories, in addition to predestination, does God actually choose by revealing Himself to those he knew from the foundation of the world?
Ephesians 1:4

According as he hath chosen us in him before the foundation of the world, that we should be holy and without blame before him in love.

God already has the number, so does he specifically reveal Himself to individuals he would like added to the list above?

The question lacks focus. God 'reveals' himself (that is to say he manifests his existence) in many ways. Through the Creation. Through Judgments. By angelic presence. Through his faithful servants and ministers. The question is generalising together all these means. Many were healed, miraculously, by Jesus. But only few followed him as disciples. God 'appeared' in a pillar of fire by night and in cloud by day, in the wilderness. And multitudes who saw, fell in the wilderness through unbelief. Regeneration, the new birth, the anointing, is within. in Spirit.

Jesus explained: "I am the way, the truth, and the life; no man cometh to the Father, but by me. If ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also: and from henceforth ye know him, and have seen him... he that hath seen me hath seen the Father... blessed are they that have NOT seen, and yet believe." John 14:6-9 & 20:29 Billions of saved people have never seen either Christ or the Father, but have heard Christ, believed, and found salvation in Him. What a blessing!

@Anne, may God bless you profoundingly for the work you are doing on this site.

In the Bible, God also reveals himself to people he did not save, such as Pharaoh and some rulers in the book of Daniel. The mere act of God appearing does not guarantee that a person will obey in faith. Look at Cain. God spoke to him in warning yet Cain did not obey but killed his brother. Then consider the many people in Exodus who witnessed the miracles yet perished in the Wilderness in various rebellions.
